# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser Script Access Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, browser

I am currently having issues with some portals that I have built using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser they are not loading content correctly as is happening in IE.

I have set the emulation to use IE11 using FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION and I dont understand why it is not acting like the installed IE11.

It is displaying "Script Access is denied in you browser" or not loading the content at all saying that I need to upgrade my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code has an issue. Check [Internet Feature Controls (B..C)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Value 11001 - forces webpages to be displayed in IE11 edge mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive. You need IE11 installed on the target system.

```
private static void WebBrowserVersionEmulation()
{
    const string BROWSER_EMULATION_KEY = 
    @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
    //
    // app.exe and app.vshost.exe
    String appname = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";
    //
    // Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 edge mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
    const int browserEmulationMode = 11001;

    RegistryKey browserEmulationKey =
        Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BROWSER_EMULATION_KEY,RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree) ??
        Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(BROWSER_EMULATION_KEY);

    if (browserEmulationKey != null)
    {
        browserEmulationKey.SetValue(appname, browserEmulationMode, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        browserEmulationKey.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still gives a "script" access error. Perhaps this is an issue with Flash?